# alias in case when sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wrote a trigger to update status to Order from OrderDetails status:

```
BEGIN
    /* 
        Order Status:
            Pending = 0,
            Processing = 1,
            Proceeded = 2,
            Completed = 3,
            Cancelled = 4,
        Order Detail Status:
            Pending = 0,
            Processing = 1,
            Proceeded = 2,
            Emailed = 3,
            Ordered = 4,
            Cancelled = 5
    */
    IF (UPDATE([Status]))
    BEGIN   
        UPDATE [Order]
        SET [Status] = 
            CASE (SELECT MIN(od.[Status]) FROM OrderDetail od WHERE od.OrderId = i.OrderId)
                WHEN 5 THEN 4
                WHEN 4 THEN 3
                WHEN 3 THEN 2
                WHEN 2 THEN 2
                WHEN 1 THEN 1
                WHEN 0 THEN 0
            END
        FROM INSERTED i
        WHERE [Order].Id = i.OrderId
    END
END
```

You can see, WHEN OrderDetailStatus = 2 OR 3 THEN OrderStatus = 2, otherwise OrderStatus = OrderDetailStatus. For now, I have to list the values of status.
So, is it possible to create a alias for value statement, like this:

```
SET [Status] = 
            CASE (SELECT MIN(od.[Status]) FROM OrderDetail od WHERE od.OrderId = i.OrderId) AS val
                WHEN 3 THEN 2
                ELSE val
            END
        FROM INSERTED i
        WHERE [Order].Id = i.OrderId
```

Comment: I can't really see a problem with what you have, in all honesty. Perhaps, instead, you could move the subquery into the `FROM` by using an `APPLY`, but that's about it.

Comment: @Larnu The problem is, the value from the select clause in CASE will be used for assignment in WHEN, but it will not be re-used, so I have to select once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think to "shorten" this would be:

```
UPDATE O
SET [Status] = CASE WHEN od.[Status] BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN od.[Status] - 1 ELSE od.[Status] END
FROM [Order] O
     JOIN INSERTED i ON O.Id = i.OrderId
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(od.[Status]) AS [Status]
                  FROM OrderDetail ca
                  WHERE ca.OrderId = i.OrderId) od;
```

*On a different note, you should really avoid using reserved (or even key) words for object names. `ORDER` is a reserved word in SQL Server, so should really not be used. `Status` is a key word, so can be, but should also be avoided.*

Comment: Oh, I think you're right. I have never used CROSS APPLY before. It's my fault